# How to use bokeh slider to update plot range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I am making a Bokeh dashboard in Python 3, and one of my main plots in-progress is a scatterplot.  I have the entire plot made, but I am looking for a way to have two sliders (x and y) to specify the range displayed based on where they are slid to.

```
p6 = figure(title = 'Average Duration and Number of Calls by Topic in Top Departments',
        y_range=(0,13000), tools=["hover", 'box_zoom', 'reset', 'save'], tooltips="@Topic; @Seconds seconds of average duration; @Count total calls")
```

My not working slider code is like this:

```
y_range_slider = RangeSlider(start=0, end=13000, 
    value=(0,13000), step=20, title="Zoom by Number of Total Calls")


def callback(attr, old, low, high):

    low, high = y_range_slider.value

    #what do I need to do here to update range??

slider.on_change('value', callback)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the values to update the range start/end:

```
def callback(attr, old, low, high):
    low, high = y_range_slider.value

    p6.y_range.start = low
    p6.y_range.end = high
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to pair it with Javascript because I am not on a Bokeh server.

Comment: @jdbul33: Please accept the answer if it solved your issue (click on the small check next to the answer which then turns green).